# CustomLog responds but there are no output on client

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, connection

So my friend had a server that responds incorrectly, for example this request:

```
time curl -vv 'http://x.x.x.x/~a/fsocial/json_eod_per_code/PTBA-2014-2-c.json'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 80 (#0)
> GET /~bei50001/fsocial/json_eod_per_code/PTBA-2014-2-c.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: x.x.x.x
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

real    2m0.398s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.000s
```

but on the custom log, it shows as 200 OK:

```
my.ip.addr.es - - [03/Jul/2014:06:25:33 +0400] "GET /~a/fsocial/json_eod_per_code/PTBA-2014-2-c.json HTTP/1.1" 200 2371 "-" "curl/7.37.0"
```

is there anything else i should check? the `httpd.conf` seems ok, he said that it just happened suddenly today..

and the `mtr` result seems ok also.

when tested locally on that server using `curl`, it gives a response immediately.

i also tried the same thing using `nginx`, but it still happened..

Comment: Sounds like a network issue rather than a server issue. Your apache server is sending the response, but something is blocking it in between apache and the client. Did you make any firewall changes around the time that it stopped working?

Comment: no, some response are ok, but some are not.. for example `http://x.x.x.x/~a/fsocial/json_eod_per_code` and `http://x.x.x.x/` --> received correctly, but others are not, the file permission is `755`

Comment: If the server logs that the responses have been sent, then that means the server has sent the responses. You need to look at network problems. You might try doing a `tcpdump`.